# Can I distribute (and not develop) my iOS app on the app store using Windows machine

Tags: iphone, ios, windows

I had asked someone else to develop an iphone app. I was able to create all the necessary certificates etc. necessary for app distribution. I have also uploaded the primary details for the app in itunes connect. I have now got the binary file from the developer. Is it possible to upload the app myself. I don't have a MAC.I can't find any option to upload the binary file

Comment: What most people do is they get a cheap Mac just to do the publishing with, as well as code signing if you should ever need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need a Mac machine for app store submission process. I have launched 2 ios apps from Mac machine. I have set up the primary details and make ready the iTunes account to "Ready for upload" status. After i made it in iTunes i upload the binary from Xcode4.2. In XCode first we have to validate the binary if the binary validated successfully we can submit the binary to apple app store. This is the way i following. My lead also said that we need a Mac machine for this process. I hope it will help you a little bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For submission to appstore you need mac ios. if you don't have mac. get a virtual machine and install mac on it if your processor suport virtualization technology. Mostly newly processor supposrt it like core series.