# Deploying iOS app without Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, deployment

I have developed an iOS app which now should be deployed into the app store. The problem is, that my client want to do this on his own.

What steps are necessary? And is it possible to deploy the app without Xcode or even from a Windows PC?

Thank you for your help...

Comment: Please see below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411341/can-i-distribute-and-not-develop-my-ios-app-on-the-app-store-using-windows-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below link.

For submission to appstore you need mac ios. if you don't have mac. get a virtual machine and install mac on it if your processor suport virtualization technology. Mostly newly processor supposrt it like core series

[Can I distribute (and not develop) my iOS app on the app store using Windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411341/can-i-distribute-and-not-develop-my-ios-app-on-the-app-store-using-windows-mac)

Comment: This should be a comment as you are merely quoting from one answer given in the link. You have not added anything new in it.

Comment: yes so what...? User directly see this comment without redirecting on link thats why I put that comments at here and also provide link as well... whats wrong...?

Comment: See first of all I did not downvote your answer. Second, I suggested you should comment so as to avoid duplicity in SO. It does not help anyone to ask and answer duplicate questions if it can be avoided. Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled.

Answer (score 0):

Build your App into an .app file with a "Release" schema:

xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" -configuration Release
Package your App as an .ipa:

/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${RELEASE_BUILDDIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.ipa" --sign "${DEVELOPER_NAME}" --embed "${PROVISONING_PROFILE}”
Then, run Application Loader (Download/Install Application Loader if necessary):

open -a /Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application\ Loader.app

Try this Way using Application Loader [Application loader for submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924085/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-without-xcode)